# Populating DataGridView In C# DataTable Gives An Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to populate a Data GridView in C# using SQL Server.

The database connection to the SQL Server is inserted using App.config file.

The Data Connection is correct and I have tried to insert data to the SQL Database Table and it worked perfectly.

Please refer the below code snippets.

***App.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
      <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="MyDbConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=CHIRANTHAKA-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" />
     </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

The data will be inserted using ***InsertInfo Form***
Please refer the below code snippets for ***variable declaration***.

```
public partial class InsertInfo : Form
{
    private SqlConnection SqlConn;
    private SqlDataReader SqlRead;
    private SqlCommand SqlComm;
    private DataTable SqlDataTable;
    private SqlDataAdapter SqlAdapt;
    private DataSet DsMyData;
    private string strQuery;

    private string strDataId;
    private string strDataDesc;
    private DateTime dtmDataDate;
    private int intDataQty;

    private int intUserExist;

    public InsertInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The database connection is made in the load(). This works perfectly. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
    private void InsertInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ConnectionStringSettings ConnStrSett = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnectionString"];
        string ConnString = ConnStrSett.ConnectionString;

        try
        {
            SqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
            SqlConn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Database connected!", "DB Connection With App.Config", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My issue is with populating the ***Datagridview***.
Please refer the below code snippet.

```
 private void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
            try
            {
                SqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataTable";
                SqlDataTable = new DataTable();
                SqlAdapt.Fill(SqlDataTable);
                dgvInsertInfo.DataSource = SqlDataTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }   
    }
```

I got the below error when I click the btnShowData button.
[image]

I can't understand what I have done wrong?

Comment: That's what happens when you use unnecessary global variables. They create only problems. Declare and initialize your variables locally and discard them when you have finished

Comment: Hi Steve,
Thanks for your reply. But I haven't used any global variables. All the variables are declared in the form level.

Comment: Those are global variables (for the code inside the form class) and they aren't initialized anywhere (at least in the code shown) It is normal to fall for a Null Reference Exception then